# android studio 1.2.1.1 is running too slow on windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio

I reviewed different related postings on this site and also applied offered solutions like;

- Enable power save mode
- Update 'gradle.properties' file with 'org.gradle.daemon=true'

But no success, Android is running/compiling very slow, even i am not using emulator.

My Laptop specifications are Windows 7 (64 bit) with 4 GB RAM and Intel core i5 processor.

Comment: Any guideline please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Android studio root and edit studio.exe.vmoptions Change the following options.

```
-Xms512mb
-Xmx1024mb
```

Comment: Thanks, it slightly helped me... :)

Comment: If i am not wrong, probably I need to get some better specification computer... ?

Comment: @AmaraGul Please be aware of that there are two studio.exe.vmoptions one is for 32bit system the other is 64bit. Make sure to change all of them.  I think your device is quite decent.

Comment: many thanks.. you are right i got two files and previously I updated the wrong one...  again many thanks for helping.

Comment: yes this helped me... do you want me to accept your post as answer ? I am very new on this site, please share how to rate your answer?